# Django Change Variable From DataBase on Referencing

Tags: python, django

I'm currently learning Django and I wanted to start off with a really simple blog app. I have a model for my post:

```py
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()
```

Then I'm referencing it on my home page template:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %} 

{% for post in object_list %}

<div class="post-entry">
  <h2><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
  <p>{{post.body}}</p>
</div>

{% endfor %} 

{% endblock content %}
```

I would like to make `post.body` to be only first 50 or so characters but `post.body[:50]` returns syntax error. How could I do that?

Comment: ```{{ post.body|truncatechars:50 }}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

You can use

```
{{ post.body|truncatechars:50 }}
```

> It will display only 50 characters of your Post Body